# exporting a processing sketch that uses microphone input to webpage

Tags: processing, processing.js

i'm trying to get my processing sketch to work online with processing.js. It work fine when i just use a very simple processing sketch but when i try to uploade my actual code to the server it does not work

I know my code is pretty messy and stuff but i don't have time to clean up right now i just want it to show in a browser

here is my code :

`

```
/* OpenProcessing Tweak of *@*http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/5488*@* */
/* !do not delete the line above, required for linking your tweak if you upload again */
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;

Minim minim;
AudioInput in;
FFT fft;

float loudestFreqAmp = 0;
float loudestFreq = 0;
int timerCounter = 0;

/* @pjs preload="picture.jpg"; */
PImage img;
PImage noise;

void setup()
{
 size(640, 1136, P2D);
 frameRate(1);

 img = loadImage("DD.jpg");



 minim = new Minim(this);
 minim.debugOn();
 background(img);


 noStroke();
 // get a line in from Minim, default bit depth is 16
 in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 1024);
 fft = new FFT(in.bufferSize(), in.sampleRate());

}


void draw()
{


 fft.window(FFT.HAMMING);

 println();
 for(int i = 0; i < fft.specSize(); i++)
 {

   // draw the line for frequency band i, scaling it by 4 so we can
   //see it a bit better
   //line(i, height, i, height - fft.getBand(i)*4);

   // hvis fft.getBand(i) større end loudestFregAmp og fft.getBand(i) større end 10)
   if (fft.getBand(i) > loudestFreqAmp && fft.getBand(i) > 2)
   {
     //println(loudestFreqAmp);
     loudestFreqAmp = fft.getBand(i);

     //println(fft.getBand(i));


     loudestFreq = i * 4;

    println(i);
     //sine.setFreq(loudestFreq);


     //fill(loudestFreq * 1, 30 - loudestFreq, loudestFreq * 20, 30 );
     if(loudestFreq < 10)
     {
       rect(random(0,width), random(0,height), loudestFreqAmp, loudestFreqAmp);   
     }
     else
     {
         fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);
        fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

      fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

           fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

      fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

     fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

      fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

           fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

      fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);
      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

      fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

           fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

      fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

     fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

      fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

           fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);

      fill(0);
      ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),1,1);

      fill(3);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);


      fill(6);
    ellipse(random(0,width), random(0,height),2,2);
    //ellipse(loudestFreqAmp, loudestFreqAmp, random(1,width), random(1,height) );




 }


     timerCounter = 0;
   }
 }
 loudestFreqAmp = 0;

 // draw the waveforms
 /*  for(int i = 0; i < in.bufferSize() - 1; i++)
  {
  line(i, 50 + in.left.get(i)*50, i+1, 50 + in.left.get(i+1)*50);
  line(i, 150 + in.right.get(i)*50, i+1, 150 + in.right.get(i+1)*50);
  }*/

 fft.forward(in.mix);
 timerCounter++;
 if(timerCounter >= 90)
 {
   //println("Clr screen");
   fill(255, 255, 255, (timerCounter - 90) * 2);
   rect(0, 0, width, height);
  // point(width, height);
 }

}



void stop()
{
 // always close Minim audio classes when you are done with them
 in.close();
 minim.stop();

 super.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because minim (and most Processing libraries) are made in Java. When you are in "Java mode" your sketch is also in Java. When though you go to "Javascript mode" and you upload to server, your sketch is translated to javascript (a different language) but your library is not, thus it can not run. Your best bet is probably to find a way to embed your sketch as a Java applet!

Comment: there is an applet export tool, installed from tools installer, in Processing 2